# Agregación y trabajo con Listas en Java

Tags: java, arraylist, genericos, agregación

Estoy realizando un problema en el cual dispongo de una clase PqManager que se muestra en el código, y que mediante una relación de agregación se relaciona con Cliente. 
Desde la clase PqManager debo poder dar de alta a un cliente con dos parámetros e insertarlo en la lista clientes.
La lógica me dice que debo crear un cliente y mediante un add insertarlo en la lista. El caso es que el ser Cliente clase y tipo parámetro no lo doy hecho.
Seguro que es una tontería, pero agradecería mucho una ayudita.

Clase PqManager

```
    public class PqManager<Cliente, Paq_id, Paquete> {


     private List<Cliente> clientes;
         private Map<Paq_id, Paquete> paquetes;

         public void altaCliente (String pId, String pNombre){
           Cliente clip =  new Cliente(pId,pNombre);
           clientes.add(clip);
     }
  }
```

Clase Cliente

```
public class Cliente<Cliente> {
    private String id;
    private String nombre;

    Cliente(String pId, String pNombre){
        this.id = pId;
        this.nombre = pNombre;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo tu problema.. ese codigo parece bien.. no anda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que aún no has entendido el uso de genéricos. Simplemente para tu caso

```
public class Cliente<Cliente> {
```

El tipo Genérico sale sobrando.
Como buena práctica, en vez de ponerle el nombre de un tipo de clase concreto siempre ponle el tipo de una clase abstracta o una palabra que te indique que tipo de cosa puede ir allí, ya si no se te ocurre nada, lo común es usar `T` y `G`.

```
public class Cliente<MitipoDeDato> {
    private String id;
    private String nombre;

    Cliente(String pId, String pNombre){
        this.id = pId;
        this.nombre = pNombre;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Como verás si lo cambiamos evidenciamos que tu tipo genérico no se usa en ninguna parte, es decir. Sale sobrando.

Lo mismo se entrevee en tu otra clase. Para hacer notar el punto de como lo vel el compilador:

```
public class PqManager<客户, 数, 包> {


     private List<客户> clientes;
         private Map<数, 包> paquetes;

         public void altaCliente (String pId, String pNombre){
           客户 clip =  new 客户(pId,pNombre);
           clientes.add(clip);
     }
  }
```

El compilador no es inteligente como tú y como yo, así que no sabrá qué está pasando, no va a saber el número de parámetros que debe de recibir `客户`

por ello **no se puede hacer new con un genérico** así nomás con el new.

¿Cómo le ayudamos al compilador?

usando `extends` para indicarle que puede ser una subclase o la misma clase, por ejmplo

```
public <客户 extends Usuario, 数 extends Number, 包 extends Paquete> class PqManager<客户, 数, 包>{
```

Ya nos permite entrever un poco más que clases pudemos aceptar.

Por lo tanto, a pesar de que la sintaxis no es tan intuitiva, los genéricos nos permiten reducir códio y amplar los tipos posibles de datos que podemos manejar sin perder de vista en algún momento las reglas de nuestro... espacio vectorial (supongo, no soy tan versado en álgebra / estructuras algebraicas).

Las restricciones de un genérico [actualmente](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html) son:

- No puedes crear instancias directamente con el new(hay truco, pero eso merece otra pregunta)
- No puedes declarar campos estáticos con el tipo genérico
- No puedes hacer instance of o casting (igual hay truco para el casting)
- No puedes instancias arreglos de tipo parametrizado
- No puedes poner genéricos a nivel de clase para una excepción
- No puedes hacer un catch para un tipo genérico de excepción
- No puedes sobrecargar tu método que use genéricos (por el borrado de tipos)